# Как настроить доступ к phpMyAdmin через SSH туннель?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

В общих словах, разумеется. И достаточно ли это надежный способ защиты?
Сервер: Ubuntu. Клиент: Windows. Спасибо.

Comment: virtualhost с phpMyAdmin забайндить на 127.0.0.1. Главное, чтобы он нигде не торчал наружу. Ну, и бросить туннель до него..

Answer (score 1):

Отдельно настройте туннель по любому из многочисленных мануалов в сети. Например, http://avz.org.ua/wp/2010/06/29/putty-how-to-make-your-windows-useful/

А затем уже к этому локальному туннелю открывайте коннект как обычно.

В общих словах.. Putty одним концом открывает соединение к ubuntu и прокидывает порт мускуля (по умолчанию 3306) из убунты на другой конец - к вам на локалхост (на любой выбранный порт).